# What's the right way to set up long running microservices with zeit now?

Tags: node.js, microservices, vercel

I have an API endpoint to upload a file and that's currently set up via now. However, once the file gets uploaded, I need to kick off a process that handles the audio and that can take some time (potentially up to 5 minutes). How would I architect that within the `now` / `micro` frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Zeit Support team](https://spectrum.chat/zeit/now/whats-the-right-way-to-set-up-long-running-microservices~071610b6-dc83-4c1b-86e4-e49b6cbd8dc8), they advise using queues, however they don't currently (as of July 2019) support queues.